# ROC and AUC for Machine learning models without threshold

Tags: machine-learning, svm, knn, roc, auc

The thing I don't really understand is.. Why is it not possible/does it not make sense to use ROC and AUC for non-probabilistic machine learning models (or is this assumption wrong, although I have read this on several sites)?

Because.. I would say, suppose I use KNN (where there is no threshold), then, based on the number of K, you can train the model (although KNN doesn't really have a model, as it is instance-based), but still, for example: K = 1 --> 3 TP and 5 FP , K = 2 --> 4 TP and 4 FP and so on. So on this basis you could create a ROC curve, I would say..? is this also true for other machine learning models: for decision trees you could try a different number of nodes and so on, for support vector machines you could reposition the hyperplane, and in all these cases you could collect the FP/TP/TN/FN and process them into ROC curves, which would allow you to compare several ML models.

I use a binary classification, multiple supervised machine learning models (with only two classes), but I'm not sure if ROC and AUC are still applicable in such a case?

Comment: Where did you read that it doesn't make sense to use ROC and AUC for non-probabilistic machine learning models?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe I'm wrong, but I think I read it on several sites, but can't find it anymore.